Should I use "the" or "an" here after "every"?
Well, I edited an answer on the other site yesterday, and I wrote this line:

On the other hand, every object has a __proto__ property (equivalent to the internal [[Prototype]] property), which is the actual prototype of the object.

Now I'm reviewing it. I'm thinking about whether I should use "an" instead of "the". Or maybe I could be entirely wrong. Any advice?

note: I was told that the meaning of that sentence was wrong, so please just focus on the grammar...

We almost all only use the in the cited context. It would be "syntactically valid" to use a, and you  might even think that's more "logical", but mostly we just don't. I justify the on the grounds that it refers to the same individual object that has (any one particular) the internal [[Prototype]] property)

When you say "every object", you are talking about each object individually. The individual object that you are talking about is specific, so you use the definite article "the", rather than the indefinite article "a/an".
